# GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause coming after prepare statement (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query below with a dynamic where clause but I am having issue with where I am placing the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause. I don't think it is being triggered at all because the prepare statement is ahead of those clauses. But it does not simply allow me to place the clause line above the prepare statement or it gives me an error stating undefined questions in a completely different line. My question is where should the GROUP BY AND ORDER BY CLAUSE be correctly placed?

CODE:

```
$selectedstudentanswerqry = "
        SELECT
        sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, 
    ...
        FROM Student st
    ...
        ";

        // Initially empty
            $where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
            $parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
            $parameterTypes = 'i';


        //check if POST is empty

        // Check whether a specific student was selected

        $p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?0:$_POST["student"];  // Now if $_POST['student'] is either 0 or empty $p_student will be 0
    echo $p_student;
        switch($p_student){
        case 0:
            //dont' add where filters
            break;
        default:
            $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
            $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
            $parameterTypes .= 'i';
        }


        // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
        // our query
        if(!empty($where)) {
            $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
            global $mysqli;
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
            // You only need to call bind_param once

            if (count($where) == 1) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
        }
        else if (count($where) == 2) {
            $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
        }

        }

        $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
          GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
          ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
        ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the prepare statement and if statements containing the bind_param() underneath the GROUP BY/ORDER BY clause. You have a closing `}` just above `$selectedstudentanswerqry` which can be moved up  to above `if (count($where) == 1)`